# Set a password that's not linked to my Microsoft account?

Tags: windows-8, passwords, user-accounts, microsoft-account

I have a really long password for my Microsoft account, and I don't want to enter that *every single time* I log in, so I was wondering if I could have a second, smaller password for just the computer profile. I know you can do this with a PIN, or a picture password, but can I do it with a normal password?

Answer (score 4):

In Windows8, any computer you sign into with using your MS account are synced (certain profile settings), which is why the passwrods need to match us with the server.

If you wish, you are able to bring your account to the local machine and stop it from syncing with MS, which also enables you to change your password. To do this...

> Settings -> Change PC Settings -> Switch to a local account -> Change your password

Answer (score 0):

Because I already had a Microsoft account connected, I found that the process was:

> Settings -> Change PC Settings -> Accounts -> Disconnect

*Disconnect was under my Microsoft Account email address*.

From there I could choose a new local account password, pin, or picture.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP is asking. I *think* he wants to keep his Microsoft account enabled.

Comment: I wonder if something has changed because I don't see "Switch to local account" anywhere. This was the only way I could see to use a local account password.