# Use Microsoft account but with local password instead

Tags: windows-10, passwords, user-accounts, microsoft-account

So when I got Windows 10, I was trying to setup Cortana and all those other fun apps, and it asked me to log in with my Microsoft account. But when I logged in with my Microsoft account, it switched my old password to my Microsoft one.

Is there a way I can have my Microsoft account on my computer and still keep my local password? I don't want to use a picture password or a pin. Because half of the time I keep trying to enter my old password when I unlock and I have to enter my ugly Microsoft password every time.

When I have my MS account disabled, I get my old password back, but the app complains I don't have it enabled. Seems like I can't use certain apps without my MS account turned on. It's just driving me nuts!

Comment: What you want is not possible.  There is no way to use your local account password if you connect your local account to a Microsoft Account.  This was always the case for Windows 8.  [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/523486/set-a-password-thats-not-linked-to-my-microsoft-account?rq=1) is a related question.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the latest update allows Cortana to be used with a local account, fixing part of your problem hopefully.

See the link below and the section "Cortana improvements":
https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10/7695/heres-whats-new-in-the-windows-10-fall-update

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer states, the latest November update allows Cortana to work with local accounts. However, I'll go into details about it since it's not as simple and clear cut as one might think. (the other answer didn't go into the details)

You'll still need to login with a Microsoft account, but the difference now is that the Microsoft account information can be JUST for Cortana as opposed to having the Microsoft account information for BOTH Cortana and your login. (which was an all or nothing type of deal) Make sense? In other words, with the November update, you log into Cortana with your Microsoft account ONCE and still keep the ability to use a local account to log into your computer at startup/resume.

To go through step by step, you simply click on Cortana and when it asks for your Microsoft account, you go ahead and login. Afterwards (here's the important step), you need to make sure to click on the "sign in to just this app instead" link so preserve the local account you're using. See below for a screenshot.

(screenshot from www.digitalcitizen.life)

[image: screenshot]